# Creating a new date from a projected field in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to create a new date based on a projected field?

Something like [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) that is available in MongoDB 3.2.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: ... },
    {
        $project: {
            createdDate: '$dateCreated',
            diffYears: {
                $add: [
                    { $year: '$dateCreated' },
                    {
                        $subtract: [
                            { $year: { $add: new Date() } },
                            { $year: '$dateCreated' },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
            year: { $year: "$dateCreated" },
            month: { $month: "$dateCreated" },
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$dateCreated" },
            hour: { $hour: "$dateCreated" },
            minutes: { $minute: "$dateCreated" },
            seconds: { $second: "$dateCreated" },
            milliseconds: { $millisecond: "$dateCreated" },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            anniversary: { $add: new Date('$diffYears', '$month', '$day', '$hour', '$minutes', '$seconds', '$milliseconds') },
        },
    },
]);
```

Comment: could you post your sample collection

Comment: It is just a date field `{ dateCreated: ISODate('2018-08-27T00:00:00Z') }`

Comment: and what format do you want from this?

Comment: The end goal is to be able to find some documents where the `anniversary` date is exactly 30 days (excluding hours, minutes, seconds etc) from today. To be able to compare I think it needs to be in ISODate format?